# git . how to revert reset HEAD and git pull origin incoming

Tags: github

I did

```
git reset HEAD resources/views/main/index2.blade.php resources/views/main/parasat.blade.php
```

to reset only these  2 files . But got this.

```
Unstaged changes after reset:
M       .idea/deployment.xml
M       .idea/kaznaru.iml
M       .idea/php.xml
M       app/Http/Controllers/Admin/OpController.php
M       app/Http/Controllers/Front/University/UniversityController.php
M       app/Models/Relations/OpRelations.php
M       app/Models/Student/Organization/Organization.php
M       resources/lang/en.json
M       resources/lang/kz.json
M       resources/views/admin/partials/menu.blade.php
M       resources/views/main/index.blade.php
D       resources/views/main/index2.blade.php
M       resources/views/main/layouts/app2.blade.php
M       resources/views/main/modules/main/goal.blade.php
D       resources/views/main/parasat.blade.php
M       resources/views/main/programs/show.blade.php
M       resources/views/main/university/index.blade.php
M       routes/admin.php
M       routes/web.php
M       storage/framework/sessions/LiVpkl2njw1ZKESv7yHJY0f3l5nlcIgbgco2m311
```

it reseted all this list.
then I  pulled files from another branch.

```
git stash
git add .
git commit -m "saving local changes before pulling"
git pull origin incoming
```

Now can I revert all and go to state before this  `git reset HEAD` ?